# Split string into list, then split list into list of lists

Tags: python, list, split

I have a string, a sample of it looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/2FFNa3Qx

There are patterns, generally after "Sequence:" the next 22 elements repeat, these are the data that I want isolated.

So I was thinking, if I split the string at `Sequence:` into a list of elements and then split this generated list into a list of lists via `\n`, each of these lists that had a length of 22 elements would be the data I wanted. So I've tried that with this code:

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_rancli, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    //proc_stdout is the string
    proc_stdout  = proc.communicate(ran_opt_get_access_data)[0]

    parse = proc_stdout.split('Sequence:')
    print parse
    time.sleep(5)
    parse2 = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in parse] 
    print parse2
    time.sleep(5)
```

However the second of these doesn't give me what I expect, what am i doing wrong?

Actual output:

```
    parse2 = ['RAN> get ap 108352 attr=4192', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' 
', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Splitting and returning a space?

here is some of the result of the first parse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQHP.png

Comment: `proc_stdout` doesn't seem to contain what you think it contains. Are you sure that everything after "Request successful" isn't sent somewhere else, e.g. STDERR? Or that the program you're using doesn't act differently when connected to a pipe vs to a terminal?

Comment: I can print out proc_stdout and see that the string is there. However I had linewrap off so most of the answer is clipped off. i will post up what the output is soon when it is done processing, it is still wrong but will be different/longer.

Comment: So linewrap was the problem for the first parse, the second one is the problem, amended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't get what you expect is that there is whitespace between each `Sequence:` and the following newline. `[i.split('\n')[0] for i in parse]` will get the first item after splitting on newlines, which will be that whitespace.

Instead of fixing this approach, I suggest you do something slightly more sophisticated and create a dict that models your output:

```
def add_data(key, value, data):
    if key.startswith('Value('):
        if key.endswith('(int)'):
            value = int(value)
        data['Sequences'][-1].append(value)
    elif key == 'Sequence':
        data['Sequences'].append([])
    else:
        data[key] = value

def parse_lines(lineseq):
    data = {'Sequences':[]}
    for line in lineseq:
        try:
            key, value = [part.strip() for part in line.split(':', 1)]
        except ValueError:
            continue
        add_data(key, value, data)
    return data

lines = proc_stdout.split('\n')
data = parse_lines(lines)
```

This produces a data structure like so:

```
{'AttributeId': '4192',
 'AttributeList': '',
 'ClassId': '1014 (AP)',
 'InstanceId': '0',
 'MessageType': '81 (GetAttributesResponse)',
 'ObjectInstance': '',
 'Protocol': 'BSMIS Rx',
 'RDN': '',
 'TransactionId': '66',
 'Sequences': [[],
               [1,'2013-02-26T15:01:11Z'],
               [],
               [10564,13,388,0,-321,83,'272','05',67,67,708,896,31,128,-12,-109,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10564,13,108,0,-11,83,'272','05',67,67,708,1796,31,128,-12,-109,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10589,16,388,0,-15,79,'272','05',67,67,708,8680,31,125,-16,-110,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10589,15,108,0,-16,81,'272','05',67,67,708,8105,31,126,-14,-109,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10637,40,233,0,-11,89,'272','03',30052,1,5,54013,33,103,-6,-76,1,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10662,46,234,0,-15,85,'272','03',30052,1,5,54016,33,97,-10,-74,1,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10712,51,12,0,-24,91,'272','01',4013,254,200,2973,3,62,-4,-63,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10737,15,224,0,-16,82,'272','01',3020,21,21,40770,33,128,-13,-108,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10762,14,450,0,-7,78,'272','01',3020,21,21,53215,29,125,-17,-113,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10762,15,224,0,-7,85,'272','01',3020,21,21,50770,33,128,-10,-105,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10762,14,124,0,-7,78,'272','01',3020,10,10,56880,32,128,-17,-113,0,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10812,11,135,0,-14,81,'272','02',36002,1,11,43159,31,130,-14,-113,1,-20,-111,-1,-1,0],
               [10837,42,23,0,-9,89,'272','02',36002,1,11,53529,31,99,-6,-74,1,-20,-111,-1,-1,0,54],
               [13,'2013-02-26T15:02:09Z'],
               [],
               [2,12,7,0,9,70,'272','02',20003,0,0,15535,0,0,0,0,1,100,100,-1,-1,0],
               [5,15,44,0,-205,77,'272','02',20003,0,0,15632,0,0,0,0,1,100,100,-1,-1,0],
               [7,25,9,0,0,84,'272','02',20002,0,0,50883,0,0,0,0,1,100,100,-1,-1,0]]
}
```

If you then only want sequences with a length of 22, it's easy to get that:

```
len22seqs = [s for s in data['Sequences'] if len(s)==22]
# alternatively:
len22seqs = filter(lambda s: len(s)==22, data['Sequences'])
```

Comment: Very good answer, I could use this but would need to only use the lines with 22 elements, because of your answer I have noticed there are also some with 23 elements that I'll have to use. eg [10837,42,23,0,-9,89,'272','02',36002,1,11,53529,31,99,-6,-74,1,-20,-111,-1,-1,0,54],

Comment: It is very easy to either filter out sequences that are the wrong length or to truncate them to the right length. I think you want to filter, but it's not 100% clear to me. (Updated answer with how to do this.) In any case, you can't know the length of the sequence until you get it completely.

Comment: Dont fully understand add_data

Comment: @Paul, what don't you understand?

Comment: The elif and the else are confusing me.

Comment: `add_data` gets called with arguments like `('Value(int)', '-1', {'Sequences':[]})`. If the key starts with `Value(`, the value is appended to the last sequence in `data['Sequences']`. If the value is `Sequence`, it appends a new empty list (start of a new sequence) to `data['Sequences']`. Otherwise it's read as record metadata and the key-value are added directly as `data[key]=value`. Not very complicated....

Comment: ah thanks, wa sa bit confused when things like  Value(string):     2013-02-26T15:01:11Z weren't getting added.

Comment: @Paul, ah, that's not a problem in `add_data`, that's a problem with the `split` because the line contains multiple colons. (I always forget whether the second argument means "max splits" or "max pieces"!) Updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Using string you provided on pastebin (as content of variable `a`):

```python
>>> result = [i.strip().split('\n') for i in a.split('Sequence')]
>>> [len(i) for i in result]
[10, 1, 3, 1, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 3, 1, 23, 23, 23]
```

For example here:

```
       Sequence:
     Value(int):     1
  Value(string):     2013-02-26T15:01:11Z
       Sequence:
```

So let's filter only those with 23 elements (note the first element is `:`):

```python
>>> result = [i[1:] for i in result if len(i) == 23]
>>> [len(i) for i in result]
[22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

And now you have array which looks like this:

```python
>>> print( '\n'.join(result[0]))
     Value(int):       10564
     Value(int):       13
     Value(int):       388
     Value(int):       0
     Value(int):       -321
     Value(int):       83
  Value(string):       272
  Value(string):       05
     Value(int):       67
     Value(int):       67
     Value(int):       708
     Value(int):       896
     Value(int):       31
     Value(int):       128
     Value(int):       -12
     Value(int):       -109
     Value(int):       0
     Value(int):       -20
     Value(int):       -111
     Value(int):       -1
     Value(int):       -1
     Value(int):       0
```

So whole code you need with data you provided is:

```python
proc_stdout = proc.communicate(ran_opt_get_access_data)[0].decode('utf-8')
result = [i.strip().split('\n') for i in proc_stdout.split('Sequence')]
result = [i[1:] for i in result if len(i) == 23]
# Or at least [i[1:] for i in result if len(i) > 1]
```

---

#### Edit - removing value

We'll use simple hack, thus there's always only one `:` and [`string.find()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and [`string.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove white spaces:

```python
def filter_value(text):
    index = text.find( ':')
    # Not found :
    if index < 0:
        return text.strip()

    return text[index+1:].strip()
```

And implement it by replacing this line:

```python
result = [i[1:] for i in result if len(i) == 23]
```

With this one-liner:

```python
result = [[filter_value(j) for j in i[1:]] for i in result if len(i) == 23]
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like an awesome answer, going to go through tit now to try and understand it all. After that I can just remove all non-numeric characters and spaces from the arrays i take it. Did that make an array of 15 elements with each being 22 length? And why split with Sequence and not Sequence:?

Comment: @Paul it should be probably `Sequence:\n`... I used `Sequence` just because I was writing it in hurry. And yes you can see the length of each item in 3rd code sample.

Comment: @Paul you've said that you want list of lists, so I have you one :P each item of main list contains list of `Value(): -1` items.

Comment: @Paul [just try it](http://pastebin.com/YJAwxsEs) :) First result contains just `:` and some whitespaces and you want to git rid of that. `[1:]` returns everything from list except the first element in new list.

Comment: Ah I see, i was having trouble spotting the difference in the huge amount of data

Comment: Now I must try to remove all the "Value(int):       " stuff and leave all the numbers.

Comment: @Paul :D when I'm getting paid? :D there you go, edited answer.